# How to make UdpClient.Receive to listen to specific network interface?

Tags: c#, network-programming

On my machine i have 3 network adapter.
I need to listen to specific network adapter on my application.

I scan all the network adapter (using NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces Method () ) on my machine and i hold now all the network adapter that are type of Ethernet.

And i need to bind my UdpClient to one of them ( and listen to him )

How do i do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That binds `UdpClient` to specific network interface.

```
var portNum = 2000; // your port
var ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.1"); // your IP
var listenEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, portNum);
var myClient = new UdpClient(listenEndpoint);
```

Comment: if i have more then one ip address - of multi network adapter ?

Comment: If you know all your ip addresses maybe you just create multiple udp clients? One client for each IP address?

Comment: yes, possible but much overhead. i prefer to have one udp client that listern the the right ip